# guidance on particular animation in android..?

Tags: android, animation, view

I just want to get a bit of guidance on what should I google and read on to make an animation in android, somethink like 'Shazam' spining Logo, I googled a bit and stumble upon "frame animation" but I don't think it's the same sort of animation as in mentioned 'Shazam' Logo(but let me know if I'm wrong)..
P.S 
(maybe there is a site where one can buy small animation for apps -if someone knows..?:) )
 [image]

Comment: Can you explain in words exactly what you want to do?  you want to rotate an image?

Comment: Hi, sorry-have realy heard time to describe it in words thats why I gave 'shazam'logo as example - but yea it's rotate but at the same time thoese light blue strips around changing color as well- if that makes any sense :S (ty for your time sir)

Comment: read about `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` / `TimeAnimator`

Comment: ok-Thank You pskink (y)